# Why does $P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i \geq 1} A_i\right) \geq 1- \sum\limits_{i \geq 1} \alpha_i$ hold?

Tags: probability

Given a probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$.

Let $A_1, A_2, ..$ be events, $A_i\in F$.

Let $P(A_i) \geq 1-\alpha_i$ where $i \geq 1$ and $0 \leq \alpha_i \leq 1$.

Why does the following hold:

$$P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i \geq 1} A_i\right) \geq 1- \sum\limits_{i \geq 1} \alpha_i$$

Thanks a lot in advance :)

EDIT:

I see,  so:

1. If $P(A_i) \geq 1-\alpha_i$, then $P\left(\overline{A_i}\right) \leq \alpha_i$.
2. then $P\left(\bigcup\limits_{i \geq 1} \overline{A_i}\right) \leq \sum\limits_{i \geq 1} P(\overline{A_i}) \leq \sum\limits_{i \geq 1} \alpha_i$
3. and because $P\left(\overline{\bigcup\limits_{i \geq 1} \overline{A_i}}\right ) = P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i\geq 1} A_i\right)$ it holds $P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i \geq 1} A_i\right) \geq 1- \sum\limits_{i \geq 1} \alpha_i$?

Comment: Hint: use $P(\overline{A_i})\le \alpha_i$

Comment: and $P\left(\bigcup_j B_j\right) \le \sum_j P(B_j)$

Comment: @Gribouillis Edited, is that correct? :)

Comment: @Derping  s almost correct, $P$ must not be overlined, only what's inside $P()$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Fixed, thanks alot. And thanks a lot to the guy who edited the question and made it all look nice.

Comment: @Derping I just fixed the expression in the section 2, you overwrote it. You are comparing a measure (probability) with the event, which doesn't make sense ... fix it please

Comment: @rtybase oh yeah, you are right. Thanks alot

Comment: @Derping still not good :), from the section 1, you have $\leq \alpha_i$, so the sum in the section 2 should also be $\leq \sum\limits_{i\geq 1} \alpha_i$

Comment: You have subscript $i \ge i$ three times where you probably intend $i \ge 1$

Comment: @rtybase now it should be fine^^ sorry

Answer (score 0):

Comment (trouble showing it in 'comment' format):

Perhaps more compactly,
$$P\left(\bigcap_i A_i\right) = 1 -P\left[\left(\bigcap_i A_i\right)^c\;\right] \ge 1 - P\left(\bigcup_i A_i^c\right) 
\ge 1 - \sum_iP(A_i^c) \ge 1 - \sum_i \alpha_i.$$

To justify the steps: cite complement law, de Morgan, subadditivity, hints in previous comments.